# Padding the content of a RichEditBox in a C# WinRT app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, padding

I'm trying to apply padding to the top and bottom of a RichEditBox in a XAML/C# WinRT app, but it isn't producing the desired effect.

Basically, when I set the padding to these edges, the padding produces empty space that remains even when I scroll the content of the control. However, I would like it to pad the *content* of the RichEditBox, so that there is no visible empty space when the content is scrolled away from the top and bottom edges.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `Margin` in the content being drawn, as you want the content being drawn to actually enlarge as opposed to the content being drawn a certain distance away from the edge.

In order to add this `Margin`, you'll need to edit the Template, which is set in the Style. [The default style and template for the rich edit box is this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710189.aspx):

```
<!-- Default style for System.Windows.Controls.RichEditBox -->
<Style TargetType="RichEditBox">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RichEditBox">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundThemeOpacity}" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBackgroundThemeOpacity}" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBorderThemeOpacity}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                      Grid.Row="0"
                                      Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundHeaderThemeBrush}"
                                      Margin="0,4,0,4"
                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                      FontWeight="Semilight" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  IsTabStop="False"
                                  ZoomMode="Disabled" 
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  IsTabStop="False"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" 
                                  IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Notice the `ScrollViewer` is applying the `Padding` directly. Unfortunately, this is not what you want. If you replace it with a ContentPresenter which applies the `Padding` as a `TemplateBinding` to its `Margin`, it should present as you desire.

```
<ScrollViewer 
  Grid.Row="1"
  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
  IsTabStop="False"
  ZoomMode="Disabled" 
  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
      <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentElement" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Notice that you have to set the `Name` of the `ContentPresenter` to `ContentElement` so that the control logic knows about it.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: I've marked this as correct as it produces the desired effect, but for some reason that I can't work out it seems to run much slower than when I use the unedited template, especially with large documents, and editing the document becomes very laggy. This only happens when `x:Name="ContentElement"` is moved from the `ScrollViewer` to the `ContentPresenter`. Would there be any way to resolve this?

Comment: That I am genuinely not sure about. You may want to try running it through performance diagnostics to see if that provides hints as to what is taking so long with it. Where are you declaring the Style? In the page itself or in a `ResourceDictionary` merged in your `App.xaml`? If the former, try the latter and visa versa.